# String to Datetime in BigQuery

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

How do I convert the `int64` of format `yyyymmdd` into `DateTime` in Google Big Query?

My target column is `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `parse_timestamp()` and convert the value to a string:

```
select parse_timestamp('%Y%m%d', cast(20100101 as string))
```

You can also use `parse_date()` and `parse_datetime()` if those are the destination types.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution which doesn't require string construction and parsing is using `DATE` (or `DATETIME`) constructor, which can be `CAST` to `TIMESTAMP` later if needed:

```
SELECT 
  DATE(DIV(x,10000), DIV(MOD(x, 10000), 100), MOD(x, 100))
FROM UNNEST([19980201, 20101223]) x
```